# Not getting phone number in custom contact cursor adapter

Tags: android

i am trying to implement a custom cursor adapter to show contacts name and number.But i am getting only name and number is coming as null.Please help me figure out why i am getting number as null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotextContacts"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/namelabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below = "@id/namelabel"
/>
```

```
private AutoCompleteTextView destination;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    People._ID,
    People.NAME,
    People.NUMBER


};


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);
        mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                People.CONTENT_URI, PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null,
                null, null);

    if(cursor == null ){
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"cursor null");
    }
    CallListAdapter adapter = new CallListAdapter(this, cursor);
    destination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autotextContacts);
    destination.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public static class CallListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements
Filterable {
    Context context;
    private ContentResolver mContent;
    public CallListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, true);
        mContent = context.getContentResolver();
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_view, parent, false);
        TextView tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namelabel);
        tx.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME)));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rishi_label);
        tx.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME)));
        Log.i("LOG","Contact NAME" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME)));
        int numbercolumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);
        String number;
         number = cursor.getString(numbercolumn);
         Log.i("LOG", "Contact NUMBER" + number);

    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = null;
        String[] args = null;
        if (constraint != null) {
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
            buffer.append("UPPER(");
            buffer.append(Contacts.People.NAME);
            buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
            args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
        }
        return mContent.query(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI,
                PEOPLE_PROJECTION, buffer == null ? null : buffer
                        .toString(), args,
                null); 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the contacts contract api because the people api is deprecated. Probably this is causing your problems. Cou could look at this tutorial (http://app-solut.com/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/) which demonstrates the use of contacts contract but without a cursor adapter or look at the api documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Answer (score 3):

I think in below code you will get your answer.

```
if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) {
                        // Find all phone numbers

                        Cursor phones1 = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        while (phones1.moveToNext()) {
                            String number = phones1.getString(phones1
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                            int type0 = phones1.getInt(phones1
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                            switch (type0) {
                            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                // do something with the Home number here...
                                card.Homeno = number;
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                                card.MobileNo = number;
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                // do something with the Work number here...
                                card.WorkNo = number;
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                                // do something with the Other number here...
                                allphones += "\nOther No. : " + number;
                                break;
                            case Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM:
                                // do something with the Other number here...
                                card.CustomNo=number;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        phones1.close();
                    }
```

Comment: thanks  helped me a lot   I posted my solution based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
package my.package.androidapp.model;

import my.package.androidapp.R;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Contactmodel extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {

    private final Context context;

    public Contactmodel(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {

        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
        // android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
        final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

        TextView view = (TextView) l.getChildAt(0);
        view.setText(name);

        view = (TextView) l.getChildAt(1);
        view.setText(number);

        return l;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        String dName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        TextView nameV = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(0);
        nameV.setText(dName);
        TextView numV = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(1);
        numV.setText(number);

    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor c) {
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }
        System.out.println("debug search in the db");
        StringBuilder buffer = null;
        String[] args = null;
        if (constraint != null) {
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
            buffer.append("UPPER(");
            buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
            args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
        }

        return context.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PEOPLE_PROJECTION, buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(),
                args, null);

    }

    private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };

}
```